# PHP upload file to Ajax using onchange

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
function chkFile(file1) {
    var file = file1.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('formData', file);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chkFileType.php",    
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
      }
  });
}


<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />

Upload Files
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" onChange="chkFile(this)"/>

<input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Checkout">
```

chkFileType.php

```
<?php 
    print_r($_FILE)
?>
```

I want to create a form that when the user uploads a file, it will do a check on the uploaded file before submitting the whole form. I use `onChange` when a file is uploaded and then pass the `formData` value to Ajax to call my `chkFileType.php` to do the checks and alert back the response.

The function is running without any errors, but no response from `alert(data)`;

I know I am doing something wrong, but have no idea which direction to go from. Am I doing the right way?

Comment: can you add content of `chkFileType.php`??

Comment: are you getting a null message in alert or no alert box at all ? If you are getting a null message there is problem with your chkFileType.php

Comment: hi i have added the content of chkFileType.php. I am not getting any alert(data) from success function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine. You have done in right way. But to get any response from an ajax call, you have to print the required stuff in `chkFileType.php`.

Like,

```
if($ext =="jpg" || $ext == "png"){
     echo "Image"; // data in alert will alert as Image
} else if(check for txt file){
     echo "Text File"; //  data in alert will alert as Text File
} else if(chck for pdf) {
     echo "Pdf";// data in alert will alert as Pdf  
}
```

**EDIT**
change this

```
var formData = new FormData( $("#formID")[0] );
```

Hope you understand what i meant to say.

Comment: oops i forgot to show my chkFileType.php. Yes i did put the echo codes

Comment: i meant i did add the echo codes, but no response on alert(data);

Comment: what is the response you are getting in console?

Comment: If i remove dataType: 'json', i am able to get a reply 'ok' from alert(data) . but not the $_File info.

Comment: array is empty. nothing is inside

Comment: i think you have to change this, `var formData = new FormData( $("#formID")[0] );`.

Comment: yes i have fixed it, its solved :) can you add that to a actual answer so i can tick it? i will update my codes above

Comment: Why you have to specify the 0 index ? If you want to send data alongside the file/files ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in that you have written "type" instead of "method", "POST" is a method not a type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32343689)