# file upload is not working with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i have a add form.added data using ajax and codeigniter.there is a file upload in that form.but file is not uploaded.other datas are added.but the file is not uploaded to the specified folder.

View file

```
     <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="txtname">Title of Quotation Request :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtTitle" class="form-control" id="txtname"  value="<?php
        if (!empty($service)) {
            echo $service;
        }
        ?>"  required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="txtcustomer">Select Customer :</label>

        <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" required="required">
            <option value="">----Select------</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($customers as $customer) {
                echo ' <option value="' . $customer->usr_id . '">' . $customer->usr_name . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="sbMerchant">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="txtattachments">Drawing Attachments :</label>
        <input name="txtattachments" type="file" id="txtattachments">
    </div>
```

Ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#rfqsubmit').click(function () {
        //var title = $('#title').val();
     alert($('#txtattachments').val());
        var form_data = {
            title: $('#txtname').val(),
            merid: $('#mermerchant').val(),
            userid: $('#customer').val(),
            description: $('#txtrequirement').val(),
            reqid: $('#requirementid').val(),
            shipmethod: $('#shipmethod').val(),
            shiplocation: $('#shiplocation').val(),
            txtattachments: $('#txtattachments').val(),
            bidclose: $('#txtbidclose').val(),
            shipcurrency:$('#shipcurrency').val(),
            txtproduct:$('#txtproduct').val(),
            txtunit:$('#txtunit').val(),
            txtquantity:$('#txtquantity').val(),
            ajax: '1'
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addoffline",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            dataType:"Json",

            success: function(data) {
                var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+last_inserted_id;
                // window.location.href ="<?php //echo base_url()             ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+  form_data.reqid;
//      alert('added Successfully');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



</script>
```

Controller

```
public function addoffline() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->helper('file');
         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/rfqimages';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
         if (isset($_FILES['txtattachments']['name'])) {
            $filename = "-" . $_FILES['txtattachments']['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $filename;
        }
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $field_name = "txtattachments";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         if (!$this->upload->do_upload('txtattachments')) {
                //no file uploaded or failed upload
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $dat = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->resize($dat['upload_data']['full_path'], $dat['upload_data']['file_name']);
            }
        $data7 = array(
            'rfq_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'rfq_detail' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'rfq_merchantid' => $this->input->post('merid'),
            'rfq_userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),  
            'rfq_requirementid'=>$this->input->post('reqid'),  
            'rfq_shipmethod'=>$this->input->post('shipmethod'), 
            'rfq_shiplocation'=>$this->input->post('shiplocation'), 
            'rfq_bidclosing'=>strtotime($this->input->post('bidclose')), 
            'rfq_shipcurrency'=>$this->input->post('shipcurrency'),
            'rfq_productid'=>$this->input->post('txtproduct'),
            'rfq_unit'=>$this->input->post('txtunit'),
            'rfq_quantity'=>$this->input->post('txtquantity'),
            'rfq_resource'=>2,
            'rfq_dated'=>time(),
            'rfq_status'=>0,
            'rfq_ipadd'=>$ip
        );

         $inserted_id= $this->requirement_model->forminsert($data7);
         $response=array('id'=>$inserted_id,'message'=>"inserted successfully"); 
         echo json_encode($response); 
         die();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking fields like that, do like this

```
var form_data = new FormData("id of the foem");
```

Then pass this in ajax like this,

```
data: form_data,
```

Make sure, `enctype` is set for form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

In codeingiter,

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('moderator/RFQ/addoffline');?>
```

Comment: [Check this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684) for more info.

Comment: var form_data =  new FormData("#myform");{  i edited ajax function like this. but not working

Comment: did u checked the like??

Comment: i didnt getting file upload.. can u help

Comment: `var formData = new FormData( $("#myform")[0] );` try this

Comment: [Check this also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602504/php-upload-file-to-ajax-using-onchange/33602634#33602634)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97579/discussion-between-angel-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addoffline",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success:function(data){
        var last_inserted_id = data.id;
        window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+last_inserted_id;
        }
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Check what data is coming inside `addoffline()` action using 
`print_r($this->input->post())` and `print_r($_FILES)` functions. According to your output you can implement your code.
Your problem will be solved.